# Adding a count of all the related items for a doctrine2 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, doctrine-orm

I've this Query on doctrine2 that basically returns the different tags a Host have. May not be the best way to do it but it works. See, the tag<->ticket<->host are both manytomany relations.

```
$qb->select('t')
    ->from('App\Entity\Tag', 't')
    ->join('t.tickets', 'p')
    ->join('p.hosts', 'b')
    ->where('b.id = '. $this->host->getId())
    ->add('orderBy', 't.name ASC');
```

As i said the problem is not this query (that works!), but i would like to add a count there to see how many tickets the returned Tag has. 
Been tryin all day with:

```
$qb->expr()->countDistinct("p.id");
```

Or even with DQL but can't make it work, would appreciate any suggestion.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$qb->addSelect(
  $qb->expr()->countDistinct("p.id")
);
```